# Why does String::sub!() change the original of a cloned object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, clone, string-substitution

I have a struct in my Ruby code that looks somewhat like this

```
Parameter = Struct.new(:name, :id, :default_value, :minimum, :maximum)
```

later, I create an instance of this struct using

```
freq = Parameter.new('frequency', 15, 1000.0, 20.0, 20000.0)
```

At some point, I need an exact duplicate of this struct, so I call

```
newFreq = freq.clone
```

Then, I change `newFreq`'s name

```
newFreq.name.sub!('f', 'newF')
```

Which, miraculously, changes `freq.name`, too!

A simple assignment like `newFreq.name = 'newFrequency'` does not change `freq`.

Is this the way this is supposed to work?

**Edit:** Is it a good idea to use a class instead of a struct and overload `clone` to make a deep copy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`newFreq` is a shallow copy of `freq`. That means that each of the references stored inside of `newFreq` points to the object as the ones stored in `freq`. You can change where the references point independantly (`newFreq.name = newFreq.name.sub 'f','newF'`), but if you call a method that mutates the object, both `newFreq` and `freq` will be affected.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

Answer (score 8):

The `Object#clone` method performs shallow copy. You need **deep copy** to get the job done.

Follow [this link](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm) to learn about deep copy in Ruby.